# Leer array asociativo php

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo csv para asignarle mis campos de mysql a los campos que trae el csv y poder seleccionarlos desde un formulario con un select.

de momento leo el csv y lo convierto en un array asociativo con esto:

```
        $registros = array();
if (($fichero = fopen($RutaDocumentos.'/'.$_POST["Destino"].".csv", "r")) !== FALSE) { //abrimos el csv y lo leemos
// Lee los nombres de los campos
    $nombres_campos = fgetcsv($fichero, 0, ",", "\"", "\"");
    $num_campos = count($nombres_campos);
// Lee los registros
    while (($datos = fgetcsv($fichero, 0, ",", "\"", "\"")) !== FALSE) { // Crea un array asociativo con los nombres y valores de los campos
        for ($icampo = 0; $icampo < $num_campos; $icampo++) { $registro[$nombres_campos[$icampo]] = $datos[$icampo]; }
// Añade el registro leido al array de registros
    $registros[] = $registro;
}
fclose($fichero);
} //cerramos la lectura del csv
```

esto me genera el array asociativo que contiene los datos del csv. en este caso al hacerle un var_dump me muestra esto:

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(1) { ["Campo 1;Campo 2;Campo 3;Campo 4;Campo 5;Campo 6;Campo 7;Campo 8;Campo 9;Campo 10;Campo 11;Campo 12;Campo 13;Campo 14;Campo 15;Campo 16;Campo 17;Campo 18;Campo 19;Campo 20;Campo 21;Campo 22;Campo 23;Campo 24;Campo 25;Campo 26;Campo 27;Campo 28;Campo 29"]=> string(424) "Buy Electrical Direct;http://www.be-direct.co.uk;01/06/2005 04:46:48;Stoves 60cm Wide Dual Fuel Cooker;61DFDO;Stoves 60cm Wide Dual Fuel Cooker;16488;Stoves;61DFDO;;;GBP;0.00;583.99;0.00;;http://www.kqzyfj.com/click-1679007-10385498?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.be-direct.co.uk%2FproductDetails.asp%3Freferer%3Dcommissionjunction%26id%3D16488;http://www.awltovhc.com/image-1679007-10385498;;Cooking (cookers and microwaves);;;;;;;;;" } [1]=> array(1) { ["Campo 1;Campo 2;Campo 3;Campo 4;Campo 5;Campo 6;Campo 7;Campo 8;Campo 9;Campo 10;Campo 11;Campo 12;Campo 13;Campo 14;Campo 15;Campo 16;Campo 17;Campo 18;Campo 19;Campo 20;Campo 21;Campo 22;Campo 23;Campo 24;Campo 25;Campo 26;Campo 27;Campo 28;Campo 29"]=> string(528) "Buy Electrical Direct;http://www.be-direct.co.uk;01/06/2005 04:46:48;Hotpoint Ultima 60cm Gas Cooker with Sandstone Finish;EG73T;Hotpoint Ultima 60cm Gas Cooker with Sandstone Finish;16122;Hotpoint;EG73T;;;GBP;0.00;473.99;0.00;;http://www.tkqlhce.com/click-1679007-10385498?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.be-direct.co.uk%2FproductDetails.asp%3Freferer%3Dcommissionjunction%26id%3D16122;http://www.lduhtrp.net/image-1679007-10385498;http://www.be-direct.co.uk/additional/product_images/id16122.jpg;Cooking (cookers and microwaves);;;;;;;;;" } [2]=> array(1) { ["Campo 1;Campo 2;Campo 3;Campo 4;Campo 5;Campo 6;Campo 7;Campo 8;Campo 9;Campo 10;Campo 11;Campo 12;Campo 13;Campo 14;Campo 15;Campo 16;Campo 17;Campo 18;Campo 19;Campo 20;Campo 21;Campo 22;Campo 23;Campo 24;Campo 25;Campo 26;Campo 27;Campo 28;Campo 29"]=> string(548) "Buy Electrical Direct;http://www.be-direct.co.uk;01/06/2005 04:46:48;Hotpoint 60cm Electric Ceramic/Halogen Hob with Sandstone Finish;EW83T;Hotpoint 60cm Electric Ceramic/Halogen Hob with Sandstone Finish;16390;Hotpoint;EW83T;;;GBP;0.00;503.99;0.00;;http://www.tkqlhce.com/click-1679007-10385498?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.be-direct.co.uk%2FproductDetails.asp%3Freferer%3Dcommissionjunction%26id%3D16390;http://www.tqlkg.com/image-1679007-10385498;http://www.be-direct.co.uk/additional/product_images/id16390.jpg;Cooking (cookers and microwaves);;;;;;;;;" } [3]=> array(1) { ["Campo 1;Campo 2;Campo 3;Campo 4;Campo 5;Campo 6;Campo 7;Campo 8;Campo 9;Campo 10;Campo 11;Campo 12;Campo 13;Campo 14;Campo 15;Campo 16;Campo 17;Campo 18;Campo 19;Campo 20;Campo 21;Campo 22;Campo 23;Campo 24;Campo 25;Campo 26;Campo 27;Campo 28;Campo 29"]=> string(516) "Buy Electrical Direct;http://www.be-direct.co.uk;01/06/2005 04:46:48;Hotpoint 60cm Gas Cooker with Polar White Finish;GW62P;Hotpoint 60cm Gas Cooker with Polar White Finish;16402;Hotpoint;GW62P;;;GBP;0.00;495.99;0.00;;http://www.dpbolvw.net/click-1679007-10385498?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.be-direct.co.uk%2FproductDetails.asp%3Freferer%3Dcommissionjunction%26id%3D16402;http://www.tqlkg.com/image-1679007-10385498;http://www.be-direct.co.uk/additional/product_images/id16402.jpg;Cooking (cookers and microwaves);;;;;;;;;" } }
```

El caso es que ahora quiero seleccionar lo que pone campo 1, campo 2, etc para ponerlo en un select para que el usuario seleccione que es cada cosa.

No tengo muy claro como hacerlo y de momento he hecho esto:

```
<select name="ImportarCsv_Nombre" id="ImportarCsv_Nombre" placeholder="Seleccionar Articulo">
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $num_campos; $i++) { echo "<option value='$i'>".$nombres_campos[$i]."</option>"; }
                ?>
    </select>
```

El problema es que me pone todos los campos en la misma linea en vez de separarlos por option.

¿Voy bien en esta linea o me estoy complicando la vida y se podría hacer de otro modo mas sencillo?

Comment: Hola, creo que el problema principal aca es que el array que tenes separa las lineas pero no los campos, podrias intentar usando la funcion [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) en cada linea para separar los campos.

Comment: Donde en el for del select o arriba en la lectura? @Sacha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creo que el problema esta en la manera en la que llamas a la funcion [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) estas usando "," como delimitador, mientras que en tu archivo el delimitador es ";"

Comment: ¡¡Siii!! era eso. Mil Gracias...

Comment: A todos nos pasa, jaja, de nada

Comment: @Killpe  recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si resolvió el problema.

Comment: Se me pasó porque me hacia esperarme 6 minutos mas para poder darla por valida XD. lo siento sacha y @Dev.Joel